# Run windows phone8.1 app continuously in background

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8.1

Hello guys I am stuck at a point and really appreciate help, I have to keep my app running in the background continuously as it is listening to sockets and servicing them!
My app is targeted for WP8.1 using C++.
Does any one have any idea to achieve this scenario.
I have tries location tracking as suggested but no use, because as the app goes into background the app gets suspended.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do that on Windows Phone 8.1

The [ControlChannelTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.controlchanneltrigger.aspx) is designed for this connected scenario, but it isn't available on Windows Phone 8.1. It is available on Windows 8.1 and is part of the Universal API Contract so will be available on Windows 10 Mobile.